# MySQL for Excel Given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: mysql, excel

My goal is to import/export tables to MySQL in excel. I have the latest version of MySQL for Excel installed (1.3.8) and the latest version of the ODBC drivers for MySQL (8.033). When I select the name of the connection under "remote connections" in excel I'm presented with the error statement: "Connection attempt failed. The given key was not present in the dictionary."

I've tried uninstalling all MySQL downloads, and installed an older version such as 8.028, but none of the attempts worked. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

you can try reinstalling a lower version of Mysql such as Mysql 5.6.

Comment: Have you attempted this solution yourself or is this just a suggestion?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My teacher told me that I should install MySQL below version 8.0.23,but because of my previous course, I have installed MySQL 8.0.32 in physical computer,This error occurred when I was using this plugin in excel.so I installed MySQL 5.6 in VMware,and this plug-in works.I'm sorry about my poor English,but I do hope my suggesion can help you.